# Chrome extension - go to url without chrome.tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I have restrictions for including 'tabs' permission in manifest,  exist any way to go to some url without using chrome.tabs in chrome extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"tabs"` permission used to be needed for all operations, but it's not needed anymore for a long time (since [Chrome 7](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new#7)!).

The only thing that this permission grants is reading information about existing tabs.

Quoting [the documentation itself](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) (emphasis mine):

> The majority of the `chrome.tabs` API can be used without declaring any
>   permission. However, the `"tabs"` permission is required in order to
>   populate the **`url`**, **`title`**, and **`favIconUrl`** properties of `Tab`.

So you can easily manipulate tabs (e.g. create or update them) without ever needing any permission.

Also, `"activeTab"` permission is worth a look.